# Clustering using doc2vec

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, text-mining, natural-language, doc2vec

is it okay to cluster documents by learned document vectors?. I think similar documents should have similar vectors. from this fact it is okay to cluster documents using for instance k-means. However, i could not find good resource for this.

Thanks!

Comment: K-means doesn't work well in high-dimensional, noisy data. Your doc2vec dimensionality plikely is way to high.

Comment: or is it okay to apply any clustering to document vectors?

Comment: I don't agree with Anony-Mousse and strongly suggest you should at least give spherical K-means a try (i.e. using cosine similarity distance between documents). Also, you can reduce the dimensionality of your document embeddings with any factorisation technique before using them in the clustering.